# How to configure a mail channel in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-boot

I've found [Mail Integration in the Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/mail.html), a [mail channel example with XML configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/mail/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration), a suggestion to use Jasypt to encrypt the userid/password in the XML config, and an XML-based config in the Spring Boot Samples repo, but I have not figured out how to securely configure and use an email channel in a Spring Boot web app that is using annotations.

I looked for ways to incorporate XML bean definitions, and how to convert XML to annotations, but came up empty.

How should I configure **mail channels** for sending and receiving email in a Spring Boot app?

Thanks!

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to only have annotation based configuration, so I was hoping someone provide an annotation-based answer but after waiting  month, I suppose I must accept the XML-config option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spring boot integration starter doesn't include mail support; you simply need to add the `spring-integration-mail` artifact to your pom; you can then configure the mail channel adapters in XML as needed.

You can use `@ImportResource` to combine XML configuration with a `@Configuration` class.

Comment: Thanks, Gary! The tip about @ImportResource seems to be the hint I needed. I'm still not sure how to add in [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-configuration.html) so that the XML mail channel does not expose the mail user/pass, but will cross that bridge after I get a mail channel working.

Comment: I am not familiar with jasypt but the username/password is passed into javamail using a `javaMailProperties` bean as [described in the reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html).

Comment: why combine XML and pragmatically configure? and spring boot prefer pragmatically configure instead!