# How to covert xml based spring-integration-email configuration to java based config?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-java-config

I am using spring-integration-email in a spring boot application to receive emails. All example I found online use xml based config.

I am using java based config in my application and I want to use the same for the spring-integration-email.

Below is my xml based config, which works properly. How Can I convert it to java based config?

```
<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">${imap.debug}</prop>
</util:properties>

<mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
                              store-uri="${imap.uri}"
                              channel="recieveEmailChannel"
                              should-delete-messages="false"
                              should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
                              auto-startup="true"
                              java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="${imap.poolerSecondsDelay}" time-unit="SECONDS"/>
</mail:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="recieveEmailChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="DEBUG"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="recieveEmailChannel" ref="emailReceiverService" method="receive"/>

<bean id="emailReceiverService" class="com.sts.app.email.service.EmailService">
</bean>
```

Comment: As per this link Spring Boot starter do not support Java based mail configuration : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24873590/3226981

The post looks little old though..!

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted (along with some small improvements to make it more configurable) would be transformed into the following Java config:

```
@Configuration 
public class MailConfig {

    @Value("${email.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${email.from}")
    private String from;

    @Value("${email.subject}")
    private String subject;

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailService() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        javaMailSender.setHost(host);
        return javaMailSender;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage() {
       SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
       simpleMailMessage.setFrom(from);
       simpleMailMessage.setSubject(subject);
       return simpleMailMessage;
    }
}
```

also quick look on this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-email)

Comment: the code you posted is for sending the email and not for receiving the emails as in my xml config.

Comment: just checkout this link : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-using-jms-receiving, there is some configuraiton for receiving mail.

Comment: I am not using JMS, link has some jms listener etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401643/spring-receive-emails-without-xml-using-annotations-only

Comment: From one hand this answer doesn't show anything regarding Spring Integration. From other the Vinit' s comment links to the correct answer. I'd close this question as duplication.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "testReceiveEmailChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "200000", taskExecutor = "asyncTaskExecutor"))
public MessageSource<javax.mail.Message> mailMessageSource(MailReceiver mailReceiver) {
    MailReceivingMessageSource mailReceivingMessageSource = new MailReceivingMessageSource(mailReceiver);
    // other setters here
    return mailReceivingMessageSource;
}

@Bean
public MailReceiver imapMailReceiver(@Value("imaps://${login}:${pass}@${host}:993/inbox") storeUrl) {
     ImapMailReceiver imapMailReceiver = new ImapMailReceiver(storeUrl);
        // other setters here
     return imapMailReceiver;
}
```

With the Spring Integration Java DSL that may look like:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow imapMailFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(s -> s.imap("imap://user:pw@localhost:" + imapPort + "/INBOX")
                                .searchTermStrategy(this::fromAndNotSeenTerm)
                                .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.debug", "false")),
                        e -> e.autoStartup(true)
                                .poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(1000)))
                .channel(MessageChannels.queue("imapChannel"))
                .get();
    }
```

Also see the question and its discussion: [spring receive emails without xml (using annotations only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401643/spring-receive-emails-without-xml-using-annotations-only)