# How to run spring integration with multithread

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I would like to do the following with spring integration

1. Fetch files from sftp
2. Send the downloaded files to http and also to s3

Here is what I have so far.

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "100000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "3"))
    public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("sftp-inbound"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setMaxFetchSize(2);
        return source;
    }
```

Here is my service activator.
The problem with my service activator is this run in the same thread as the poller, so when the file process too long, it doesn't process the next until the first one is done.

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
        public void sftpChannel(@Payload File payload, @Header("timestamp") long timestamp) {
            log.info("Message arrived at sftpChannel");
         //do something with file
    }
```

How can I run the file process on separate thread and release the poller thread instead, so the poller can continue to pull files from sftp?

Comment: `@Poller` takes `taskExecutor` which you can configure to run asynchronously.

Comment: Please, form your comment as an answer. This is really correct.

Comment: thanks @tsolakp.
In the taskExecutor, do I only execute the task?
but then how do I configure the thread?
`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
 executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);`
for example:
`pool.execute(() -> process(payload, timestamp), 1000);`


Do you have a sample?

Comment: I dont have example but this post from @Artem Bilan might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36169903/how-to-covert-xml-based-spring-integration-email-configuration-to-java-based-con

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
    return executor; 
}
```

And use that `executor` as a bean name in the `@Poller` of the `@InboundChannelAdapter`:

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel", 
        poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "100000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "3", taskExecutor="executor"))
```

See `@Poller` JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * @return The {@link org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor} bean name.
 */
String taskExecutor() default "";
```

And also see docs in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#conditional-pollers

> Important: Async Handoff
>
> This advice modifies the trigger based on the `receive()` result. This will only work if the advice is called on the poller thread. It will not work if the poller has a `task-executor`. To use this advice where you wish to use async operations after the result of a poll, do the async handoff later, perhaps by using an `ExecutorChannel`.

Comment: I tried your example but the poller seems only run on 1 thread only :'(
`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor` keeps running on task1

Comment: Poller - true, because you use a fixedDelay, so a new task is not going to start until the finish of the current plus those 100000 milliseconds. On the other hand you 3 messages should be processed in parallel

Comment: maybe I miss understood about this inbound channel. So the poller is just to pull the files from sftp, correct? and it does pull 2 files at the time.
So in that case should I create another thread for service activator, so that I can process my file (send to http and S3) after the poller pull them on a different thread?

Comment: I guess you need to consider to use a `PublishSubcribeChannel` with an executor for parallelism and those http and S3 as subscribers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Async` annotation to run any method in a separate thread. You just need to add `@EnableAsync` in any `@Configuration` file and when you call it, it will run asynchronously. You can find more information in this [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async).